# Problems to align a Javafx button

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx, javafx-8

Newbie to JavaFX here. I'm currently working on a JavaFX project. I somehow managed to create my main window with a text, a textfield and two buttons:

However, I have some trouble positionning a button where I exactly want it to be (the red-filled box)

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngblt.png)

Here's part of my `launch` method (only the code related to the buttons). Please note that `grid` is a private GridPane attribute.

```
this.grid = new GridPane();
this.grid.setPadding(new Insets(15));
this.grid.setVgap(2);
this.grid.setHgap(2);
this.grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
submitButton.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9; -fx-background-radius: 10, 10, 10, 10;");
submitButton.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN, null, null)));

Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");

exitButton.setTextFill(Color.RED);
exitButton.setStyle("-fx-font: 20 arial; -fx-base: #dbd8d6; -fx-background-radius: 10, 10, 10, 10;");
exitButton.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null)));

this.grid.add(submitButton, 0, 2);
this.grid.add(exitButton, 1, 2);
```

How can I manage to align the Exit button more to the left, to be symetrical with the Submit button, i.e. just under the TextField?
I really appreciate your help.

**EDIT1:**
The question (Text) is at 0,0. The TextField is at 0,1.

**EDIT2**
Code for Text and TextField:

```
    TextField answer = new TextField();
    answer.autosize();
    this.answer = answer.getText();
    this.grid.add(answer, 0, 1);

    Text question = new Text("Hi there ! Press Submit to start! Exit to quit.");
    question.setFont(Font.font("Century Gothic", FontWeight.BOLD, 22));
    question.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    this.grid.add(question, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Do you want the Exit button just beside Submit or just below the end of the TextField?

Comment: I assume that the `TextField` is in `(0,1)`. Your exit button is in `(1, 2)`, which is why it is not aligned. It is in a separate column. To align, you may have to wrap the buttons in something else, and set the submit align left, while exit align right.

Comment: Create a "vbox", put the 2 buttons into, and then the vbox in the grid in (0,2) ;)

Comment: Thank you, I checked the VBox javadoc and figured out the constructor takes a `spacing` argument. What should it be in my case?

Comment: Don't create a VBox.  That way, madness lies.  Just make the text field occupy two cells, make the first button align to the left of its cell, and the second button align to the right of its cell.

Comment: Don't use an additional layout, such as a `VBox` (though I think you really meant `HBox`???). Set the column span of the text and text field to 2, i.e. `grid.add(text, 0, 0, 2, 1);` and `grid.add(textField, 0, 1, 2, 1);`. Then the buttons should be fine as they are. [Edt] your question to include the code that adds the text and text field and it will be easier to provide a complete answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace, that was a previous commenter's suggestion (sorry I cannont mention more than one user). I edited (EDIT 2) my question details to include the missing code. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text and text field span two columns:

```
TextField answer = new TextField();
answer.autosize();
this.answer = answer.getText();

// node, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnSpan, rowSpan:
this.grid.add(answer, 0, 1, 2, 1);

Text question = new Text("Hi there ! Press Submit to start! Exit to quit.");
question.setFont(Font.font("Century Gothic", FontWeight.BOLD, 22));
question.setFill(Color.BLACK);
this.grid.add(question, 0, 0, 2, 1);
```

and then make the "Exit" button right-aligned, and it should work the way you want:

```
this.grid.add(submitButton, 0, 2);
this.grid.add(exitButton, 1, 2);
GridPane.setHalignment(exitButton, HPos.RIGHT);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it's what I would have posted myself if I'd had time.  There is absolutely no point in creating an additional layout artifact (like an HBox or a VBox) when you're already using a GridPane.  It just makes maintenance far more difficult.

Comment: Thanks! It was really quick and helpful.

Comment: @Marrakchino Please mark the answer as correct if it answers you question